# Pagination jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I have a div containing a set of divs. After rendering two divs pagination is needed.Is there any jquery plugin for rending the pagination in a div..

```
<div id="parent">
  <div  id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
<div>
```

After div 2 remaining divs should go to pagination.

Answer (score 2):

a very easy solution:

use this easy plugin https://github.com/ahmedhijazi94/HZpagination.js

DEMO:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var HZperPage = 2,//number of results per page
     HZwrapper = 'paginationTable',//wrapper class
     HZlines   = 'tableItem';//items class
     HZpaginationId ='pagination-container',//id of pagination container
     HZpaginationArrowsClass = 'paginacaoCursor',//set the class of pagi
     HZpaginationColorDefault =  '#880e4f',//default color for the pagination numbers
     HZpaginationColorActive = '#311b92', //color when page is clicked
     HZpaginationCustomClass = 'customPagination'; //custom class for styling the pagination (css)
   

   /*-------------------------F/ AHMED HIJAZI -------------------------*/
   /*------------------------- HOPE YOU LIKE -------------------------*/


  function paginationShow(){if($("#"+HZpaginationId).children().length>8){var a=$(".activePagination").attr("data-valor");if(a>=4){var i=parseInt(a)-3,o=parseInt(a)+2;$(".paginacaoValor").hide(),exibir2=$(".paginacaoValor").slice(i,o).show()}else $(".paginacaoValor").hide(),exibir2=$(".paginacaoValor").slice(0,5).show()}}paginationShow(),$("#beforePagination").hide(),$("."+HZlines).hide();for(var tamanhotabela=$("."+HZwrapper).children().length,porPagina=HZperPage,paginas=Math.ceil(tamanhotabela/porPagina),i=1;i<=paginas;)$("#"+HZpaginationId).append("<p class='paginacaoValor "+HZpaginationCustomClass+"' data-valor="+i+">"+i+"</p>"),i++,$(".paginacaoValor").hide(),exibir2=$(".paginacaoValor").slice(0,5).show();$(".paginacaoValor:eq(0)").css("background",""+HZpaginationColorActive).addClass("activePagination");var exibir=$("."+HZlines).slice(0,porPagina).show();$(".paginacaoValor").on("click",function(){$(".paginacaoValor").css("background",""+HZpaginationColorDefault).removeClass("activePagination"),$(this).css("background",""+HZpaginationColorActive).addClass("activePagination");var a=$(this).attr("data-valor"),i=a*porPagina,o=i-porPagina;$("."+HZlines).hide(),exibir=$("."+HZlines).slice(o,i).show(),"1"===a?$("#beforePagination").hide():$("#beforePagination").show(),a===""+$(".paginacaoValor:last").attr("data-valor")?$("#afterPagination").hide():$("#afterPagination").show(),paginationShow()}),$(".paginacaoValor").last().after($("#afterPagination")),$("#beforePagination").on("click",function(){var a=$(".activePagination").attr("data-valor"),i=parseInt(a)-1;$("[data-valor="+i+"]").click(),paginationShow()}),$("#afterPagination").on("click",function(){var a=$(".activePagination").attr("data-valor"),i=parseInt(a)+1;$("[data-valor="+i+"]").click(),paginationShow()}),$(".paginacaoValor").css("float","left"),$("."+HZpaginationArrowsClass).css("float","left");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>HZpagination</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .customPagination, .paginacaoCursor{
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px 8px;
   color: #fff;
   background: #880e4f;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>


 <ul class="paginationTable">
              <li class="tableItem"> 1 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 2 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 3 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 4 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 5 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 6 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 7 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 8 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 9 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 10 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 11 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 12 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 13 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 14 </li>
              <li class="tableItem"> 15 </li>
          </ul>
          <div id="pagination-container">
            <p class='paginacaoCursor' id="beforePagination"> < </p>
            <p class='paginacaoCursor' id="afterPagination"> > </p>
          </div>


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="HZpagination.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a quick google search brought me [this.](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm) It is probably the nicest looking pagination out there.

Answer (score 0):

there are plugins that handle this:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination
- http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pagination

Tell us what you tried or specifically need if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

how about using https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination#readme and in the callback function you just hide and show your divs?!?!